# Access glm models in a list by name

Tags: r, glm, caret

There are a lot of glm models in a list.

```
model_list <- list(model_I, model_II, model_III...)
```

It is possible to access every model by index,
for example

```
model_list[[2]]$modelType
[1] "Regression"
```

but is there any possibility to access a single model
by its name
for example

```
model_list[[model_II]]$modelType
```

Are the names - model_I and so on - anywhere stored in an
model attribute?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think `model_list[[model_II]]$modelType` should be `model_list[["model_II"]]$modelType` and inorder to make it work, you have to use something like

```
model_list <- list(model_I = model_I, model_II = model_II)

model_list[["model_II"]]$modelType
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `lst()` from {tibble} instead of `list()` the list items will automatically be named the same as the variables you pass in.

```r
model_list <- tibble::lst(model_I, model_II)
model_list[["model_I"]]$modelType
```

or

```r
model_list$model_I$modelType
```